# No such host is known (Powershell/OCI)

Tags: powershell, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have created a linux instance on OCI. I am now trying to create an ssh connection using keys generated by OCI when I was creating the linux instance.

I am using the powershell terminal to try to connect. I am using the format:
**ssh -i'x''y'**
x being the full path directory of my private key. Y being the generic oracle opc@myinstancepublicIP.

When I run this command I get the 'no such host is known error message'. When I try to simply ping the ip address above it times out with no success.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: I realize it should ping fine but have you opened up port 22 in the OCI console? Also can you screenshot the Oracle OCI console where you see your public IP

Comment: I'm gonna be completely honest i'm a newbie. I've been given a small compartment by my boss to play around in. Does that port have to be open in the VCN i'm using?

Comment: Not the VCN.  Unfortunately I don't have access to my OCI account right now, but please go into the Oracle Compute Cloud console ( the web console where you can start/stop your  service ).  Go to the network tab and view the security rules.  See if there is a rule on port 22 set to a value of public-internet

Comment: @yaya30001996 were you able to see if Port 22 was opened? Did that resolve the issue?

Comment: @mrtaylor2112 Sorry for late reply. Yes it was resolved i had to essentially create ingress  and egress rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not reviewed this document on connecting to a linux instance using SSH on OCI, please do so - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/GSG/Tasks/testingconnection.htm

Make certain to verify the IP address to your linux instance, as well as the path to your private key file